# To create yml file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to create buildspec.yml file in eclipse. I have downloaded yaml editor and ydit from eclipse market place. How to create yaml file in src code. i could see only class and other files. not yaml. Please help on this

Answer (score 1):

It's just normal file text, Right click your wanted project -> New -> Other -> File.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you need more support you could install Yedit from Eclipse Market.
YEdit is an Eclipse editor for editing YAML files. It has the following features:

- Syntax highlighting
- Syntax checking
- Content outline
- Templates
- Various text editing support like auto-indenting and toggling of comments.
- Symfony compatibility mode. * Source formatting (experimental)

Answer (score 0):

Use  Right-click > New > Other > File and make sure its extension is `.yaml` or `.yml`.

PS: I suggest you try https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide instead of Yedit. It's a better alternative IMO.